# Connection with API while using node.js failed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner and I tried to connect to an api while using node.js.
So I tried to get the information of an simple api.

It is just a try. If anyone could help me, or has a better solution for another api, where I need an api-key it would be a pleasure for me.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
     host: 'api-sandbox.oanda.com',
     port: 80,
     path: '/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_JPY',
    method: 'GET',
};

 http.request(options, function (res) {
     var body = '';

     res.on('data', function (chunk) {
         body += chunk;
     });

     res.on('end', function () {
         var price = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(price);
     })
}).end();
```

Comment: what failed? error? what?

Comment: What is the error message, if you can tell us that we can help you much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result I've received using your details:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: openresty/1.9.15.1
Date: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 20:19:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 140
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

{
    "code" : 3,
    "message" : "This request requires authorization",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/auth\/#overview"
}
```

First of all, I'd like to recommend you using **HTTPS** protocol. Also, according to their documentation **Authentication** is required there. Please check the notes:

> "Our documentation uses the fxTrade URL for all examples. To use the
>   practice trading environment simply replace the base of the url with
>   the appropriate one listed above and follow any necessary
>   authentication."

Here is the link:
http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/authentication/

You'll see that they have **HTTPS** based requests with Authentication. Means you need to provide with Authorization headers like this:

> Authorization: Bearer 12345678900987654321-abc34135acde13f13530"

Refer to the link to see how to send HTTPS requests with options in NodeJS:

https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

In the end, you will have something like that:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'api-fxtrade.oanda.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer 12345678900987654321-abc34135acde13f13530'
  }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

  res.on('data', (data) => {
    process.stdout.write(data);
  });
});

req.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
req.end();
```

Don't forget to use your won Auth Token provided by **oanda**.